# Regex to get database URL delimiters

Tags: regex

I'm using the following regex to get delimiters between driver_type, host, port and database:

```
([^\w=]+)
```

For these URLs is almost fine

```
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
jdbc:oracle:thin://host:port/database
```

except the delimiters in the driver_type. I receive the following result:
:://:/ or ::://:/

Is it possible, using regex, to skip the ':' character(s) in driver type but get the one between host and port? The results to be something like that:
//:/ for both URLs

Thanks!

Comment: What about replacing `^[^/]+|\w+` with an empty string?

Comment: It doesn't work in my case because I want to use the regex result into Java's String.split() method

Comment: That's nice, why don't you use it inside the replace method instead?

Comment: I'm just curious whether it is possible to get all database URL components in String array using split(<regex>)? I almost did it except the full driver type but I'm not a regex expert. The idea behind is: regex returns delimiters // or ://, :, / to split method and the method builds String array like this [jdbc:oracle:thin, host, port, database]

Comment: Just do a match then `^[^/]+|[^/:\s]+`

Comment: Now I see my false. This regex returns exactly what I've asked but I need the opposite result of ^[^/]+|[^/:\s]+